# Using mockito on Objects created using new Keyword

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, testng, ibm-midrange

```
class Check{
@Autowired
As400 as400; // Is a class that creates a connection to an external system
 
Public void execute(){
CommandCall commandCall = new CommandCall(as400);  // is a class that takes the 
                                                   // connection and enables us to 
                                                   // execute commands on the external 
                                                   //system
 response = commandCall.callExternalService();
}
}
```

```
Class Checktest{

@InjectMock
Check check;

@Mock
As400 as400

@Test()
public void testExternalService(){

}
```

To write a test I can mock the As400 what about the CommandCall? how should I deal with it? As I created it with the new keyword in the implementation class, I am confused on how to use the mocked As400 with it while writing my test case

And also is the above way of coding a good practice? or am I not writing testable code?

And what care should I take while writing code so that it is easy to write test cases

Comment: Your plan is fine, so long as you mock out any calls to `As400` method calls. But, why not just `@Autowire` the `CommandCall`? Right now you aren't truly writing a unit test you are writing a test that tests both `Check` and `CommandCall` and their contract. If you need this to give you confidence then great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should also make the `CommandCall` class injectable to easily unit test your code. You could create a new configuration class and define your `CommandCall` there as a bean and inject it later in your `Check` class

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public CommandCall commandCall(As400 as400) {
   return new CommandCall(as400);
  }

}
```

and then your `Check` would only rely on `CommandCall` which you can easily mock like you did it already with `As400`

Comment: can you let me know when should i inject it as a bean and when i should not

Comment: the code above does not *inject* it as a bean, it rather declares a bean of type `CommandCall` to be autowired at any place of your application